# Why do I have to initialize the top at -1 two times in stacks?

Tags: java, stack

I am currently studying stacks and there is one thing that I do not understand. I have to create two constructors. What I don't understand is why do I have to set the top at -1 for my second constructor when my program already stacked some elements? Thanks

```
public stack () { 
    Array = new Object [MAX_ELEMENTS];
    top = -1; 
}

public stack (int elements) { 
    Array = new Object [elements]; 
    top = -1; 
}
```

Comment: You don't have to do it that way.  I can think of three distinct alternatives.  But you do need to ensure that `top` is properly initialized ... somehow ... for all ways that you can create a `stack` instance.

Comment: Also, your second constructor hasn't actually added any elements. It's using `elements` as size. Like `MAX_ELEMENTS` is a default in your first constructor.

Comment: `when my program
already stacked some elements?` Nope, you just set the stack size, but it's still empty.

Comment: Actually, if you are passing in an array that is prepopulated with elements, you maybe need an extra argument to say how many there are in the array.   Alternatively, you infer the number from the array size.  But either way, you set the `top` to the **appropriate** value.

Answer (score 1):

> why do I have to set the top at -1 for my second constructor

You don't, in general, but you do in this case because there are two separate constructors that don't call each other. There are several better solutions:

1. Initalize `top` inline, not in the constructor:

   ```
   int top = -1;
   ```
2. Chain the constructors:

   ```
   public stack () { 
       this(MAX_ELEMENTS);
   }

   public stack (int elements) { 
       Array = new Object [elements]; 
       top = -1; 
   }
   ```
3. Both.

> when my program already stacked some elements?

No it didn't. It just created an array of the size you specified.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the other answer, you can also use an instance initializer:

```
{
    top = -1;
}
```

It will be called regardless of the constructor user.